# Odd function used for signal processing?

Tags: javascript, signal-processing, fft

Ηello! I hope this is an acceptable sort of question.

Going through some code used for signal processing I came upon an odd function:

```
let kInd = (k1, pow) => {

  let k2 = 0;
  let k3 = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
    k3 = k1 >> 1;
    k2 = 2 * (k2 - k3) + k1;
    k1 = k3;
  }

  return k2;

};
```

This function is called towards the end of a fourier transform calculation to swap indexes in the real+imaginary pair of arrays:

```
let fft = samples => {

  let pow = Math.log2(samples.length); // `samples.length` is expected to be 2^int

  // ... a bunch of code to generate `rBuff` and `iBuff` arrays representing 
  // real and imaginary components of fourier values

  // Now make use of `kInd`; conditionally swap some indexes in `rBuff` and `iBuff`:
  for (let i = 0; i < rBuff.length; i++) {
    let k = kInd(i, pow);
    if (k >= i) continue;
    [ rBuff[i], rBuff[k] ] = [ rBuff[k], rBuff[i] ];
    [ iBuff[i], iBuff[k] ] = [ iBuff[k], iBuff[i] ];
  }

  // ... A bit of code to convert to power spectrum and return result

};
```

My question is: **what the heck is `kInd` doing?** I've run it to output some example values; it looks like it outputs sums of powers of 2 in a nearly random order as its `k1` parameter increments. Small changes to `kInd` lead to completely wrong results from `fft`.

Thanks!

(Note: let me know if more code would help. Trying to keep this as brief as possible for the reader's sake!)

Comment: Why not ask the programmer who wrote it?

Comment: I'd love to! No longer available.

Comment: just by looking at the code, it goes through each bit of k1 from right to left, then set k2 = k2*2 for 0 and k2 = k2*2+1 for 1, not sure why this number is relevant.

Comment: It looks like (a variant of) bit reversal, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit-reversal_permutation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This implements the [butterfly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_diagram) operation of the FFT algorithm.

For example, running...

```
console.log([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(i => kInd(i, 3)))
```

...prints...

```
[ 0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7 ]
```

... which is the mapping in the diagram here:

http://www.alwayslearn.com/DFT%20and%20FFT%20Tutorial/DFTandFFT_FFT_Butterfly_8_Input.html

Comment: AHA!! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it directly answers your question better than mine!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some kind of reordering.

```js
let kInd = (k1, pow) =>{
  let k2 = 0;
  let k3 = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
    k3 = k1 >> 1;
    k2 = 2 * (k2 - k3) + k1;
    k1 = k3;
  }
  return k2;
};

const format = (s, p = 5) => s.toString().padStart(p);

var i,
    l = 16,
    pow = Math.log2(l);
    
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    document.getElementById('out').innerHTML += `${format(i)} ${format(kInd(i, pow))}<br>`;
}
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

For any given `pow`, feeding in an incrementing `i` produces a cycle of `k`s. The cycle's length is `2^pow` The code below will show two cycles over an increasing `i` for each `pow`. What's interesting is the pattern of `i`s that result in `k`s that are greater than or equal to `i` (shown in bold in the output below).

For each pow, what's the pattern of `k(i) >= i` starting with `i=0`:

Pow 0: `TFFF...`

Pow 1: `TTFFF...`

Pow 2: `TTFTFTFFF...`

Pow 3: `TTTTFTFTFFF...`

Pow 4: `TTTTFTTTFTFTFFFTFFF...`

Pow 5: `TTTTTTTTFTTTFTTTFTFTFTFTFFFTFFFTFFF...`

```js
let kInd = (k1, pow) => {
  let k2 = 0;
  let k3 = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < pow; i++) {
    k3 = k1 >> 1;
    k2 = 2 * (k2 - k3) + k1;
    k1 = k3;
  }
  return k2;
};

for (let p = 0; p < 7; p++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, p) * 2; i++) {
    let k = kInd(i, p)
    if (k >= i) {
      $('#output').append("<p><b>" + i + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + p + "->" + k + "</b></p>");
    } else {
      $('#output').append("<p>" + i + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + p + "->" + k + "</p>");
    }
  }
  $('#output').append("<p>----------------</p>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

I know this isn't an answer but I wanted to help and a comment wasn't suitable for the formatting I wanted to put here.